# Django. How to call a python function from HTML button without reloading page?

Tags: python, django, ajax, django-forms, django-views

I want to call a python function in the backend without reloading the page.
Like this:

*index.html*

`<button name="button" onclick="run_function(param1, param2)">Run</button>`

*views.py*

```
some_function(param1, param2):

    return(param1, param2)
```

Please don't answer with "learn the whole django documentation by hard!" i have already done some research, however I havn't quiete found any working code for my case.

Comment: You would need to use Ajax. And no, this has nothing to do with the Django documentation.

Comment: I am aware of that, however every javascript7ajax code I tried that was posted online and on stackoverwflow never really worked for me. And I don't really want to study the whole ajax, js and jquery docuimentation either.

Comment: Well unfortunately you are going to have to learn if you want to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So at last I solved this issue myself. 
[This](https://realpython.com/django-and-ajax-form-submissions/)  helped alot.

*index.html*

```
<button name="button" onclick="run_function(param1, param2)">Run</button>
```

*script.js*

```
function run_function(param1, param2){
    console.log("running");
    $.ajax({
        url : "random_url/", // the endpoint
        type : "GET", // http method
        data : { param_first : param1, 
                param_second : param2 }, // data sent with the get request

        // handle a successful response
        success : function(json) {
            console.log("success"); // another sanity check
        },

        // handle a non-successful response
        error : function(xhr,errmsg,err) {
            console.log(xhr.status + ": " + xhr.responseText); // provide a bit more info about the error to the console
        }
    });
};
```

*views.py*

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
import json

def some_func(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        param1 = request.GET.get('param_first')
        param2 = request.GET.get('param_second')
        print(param1, param2)


        response_data = 'successful!'

        return HttpResponse(
            json.dumps(response_data),
            content_type="application/json"
        )

    else:
        return HttpResponse(
            json.dumps({"nothing to see": "this isn't happening"}),
            content_type="application/json"
        )
```

*urls.py* (don't know if this step was necessary)

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('random_url/', some_func)
]
```

**Also make sure that you got the uncompressed jquery package.**

Comment: Hi. Where does the `json` come from in `script.js`?

Comment: @TheSprinter in the views.py you see inside the function an HttpResponse function that sends out a json response.

Answer (score 0):

The python code is actually running on the server. That's why you need to "reload" the page to make a python code run. Actually, when you do that, you are sending a request to the server, which will run the python code and will return you a proper populated HTML page as a response.

If you want to run some code from the browser, you can use JavaScript to define a function that will be called when a click event is triggered.

More info on:

[Article about Client-Server architecture](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-the-web-works-part-ii-client-server-model-the-structure-of-a-web-application-735b4b6d76e3/)

[Introduction to JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Introduction)

Comment: can you write me an example code. I could use ajax. I am aware of that, however every javascript7ajax code I tried that was posted online and on stackoverwflow never really worked for me. The links you posted are not really useul and not rreally specific to my problem with django.